# Revert commits and only reapply some of them

Tags: git, git-revert

I know this has to have been asked before, but I'm struggling to hit an accurate enough search to find an answer.

In my repo, I have a bad commit followed by two good commits. I need to remove the bad commit but retain the good ones. How can I do this?

I imagine I have to revert to the first good commit that follows the bad one, stash the changes that are now untracked, revert the bad commit, then re-commit the stashed changes?

#### Edit:

My question was not accurate. I actually have bad merge, followed by two good commits. I feel like this is a different scenario, and the original (incorrect) question has already been answered, so I'll ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer: Just revert the bad commit.

Longer answer: Basically you have 2 options here:

1. The 2 good commits are not related to the bad commit.
   If they don't touch the same files or the same areas in the file, you can simply revert the 'bad' commit and it should work with no conflicts.
2. A good commit is related to the bad commit. In this case you would have conflicts trying to revert the 'bad' commit.
   How ever, even if you remove the good commit, and then remove the bad commit. You will still have conflicts trying to re-apply the good commit.

So bottom line - just revert the bad commit, and fix any conflicts you may have.

Comment: Sorry, I asked the wrong question - would this approach still work if the bad *commit* was actually a *merge*?

Comment: This seemed to do the right thing, when used with the `-m` option. My erroneous merge has been reverted by applying a new commit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it's a private branch and no one else has seen it and put themselves on top of it, consider rewriting history to remove the bad commit:

```
git checkout my-branch~3 # go to the revision previous to the one that is bad
git cherry-pick my-branch~2..my-branch # apply only the last two commit from my branch
# if you like the result
git branch -f my-branch # set my-branch where I am
git checkout my-branch
```

That should do

Comment: I actually asked the wrong question - would this approach still work if the bad *commit* was actually a *merge*?

Comment: If you want to _not_ include the code that was merged on my-branch~2? Yes, it would.